# Access IHttpContextAccessor inside an extension class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to access IHttpContextAccessor instance inside an extension class?

I have a DateTime extension class and for some functions I need to access IHttpContextAccessor to get user Claims.

For example:

```
public static DateTime ToClientDateTime(this DateTime value)
{
    var offset = ////get user timezone from claims here ///
    return value.AddHours(offset ?? 0);
}
```

Maybe I using an incorrect approach and maybe I have to change all my extension class to a DateTimeService that could be injected when needed.

Comment: Pass it to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is pass it to your method as a parameter like this.

```
    public class ClientsController
    {
        public IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
        public ClientsController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {   // Inject Here
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToClientDateTime(httpContextAccessor);
        }
    }

   public static class DateTimeExtensions
   {
         public static DateTime ToClientDateTime(this DateTime value,IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            var offset = ////get user timezone from claims here ///
            return value.AddHours(offset ?? 0);
        }
    }
```

Another option is to use Service Locator but this is an antipattern and hide dependencies from client and makes your code untestable.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ToClientDateTime(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var accessor = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var offset = ////get user timezone from claims here ///
        return value.AddHours(offset ?? 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the service approach? Pass context to a date function looks too weird.

Comment: Yes , i agree . That approach is better .

Comment: @Beetlejuice, if you are talking about using service locator `anti-pattern` that is not good idea. That's why it is called `anti-pattern` (you can google about it). It may help resolve your problem, but it will create issues in future (e.g. during writing unit tests)

Comment: No we are talking about creating a DateTimeService class instead of extension methods .

Comment: Then it is good approach. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access `IHttpContextAccessor` in extension methods is to pass it to a method as a parameter.

You can't use dependency injection with static classes.

```
public static DateTime ToClientDateTime(this DateTime value, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    var offset = // use httpContextAccessor
    return value.AddHours(offset ?? 0);
}
```